# Can't start another bounty after rewarding one on the same question

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

I had [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052742/sql-getting-count-of-each-category) with 2 answers that deserve extra reputation, so I started a bounty and rewarded one of the answers 11 days ago.

However, now the `start a bounty` option is not there to reward the other answer: any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're talking about your [most recent bountied question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052742/sql-getting-count-of-each-category).

You may offer multiple bounties on a question, but you must double the bounty each time: since you offered 200 reputation last time, you must offer 400+ rep this time. Since your current reputation is 271, you do not have enough to offer a second bounty.

From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> Note that if you offer several bounties on the same question, you will
>   have to double the amount each time (or more). That is, if your first
>   bounty was worth 50 reputation, your second bounty on the same
>   question will have to be for at least 100, your third for at least 200
>   and so on.

Comment: But that really strange i really don't get why it should be doubled other than a stack exchange programmer felt like writing an extra if statement

Comment: @FPGA It's meant to prevent the same user from offering bounties indefinitely. A 30k user could offer 50-rep bounties for quite a while. Once you get up to 500, it stops doubling: all future bounties are 500. Note that if *a different user* decides to put a bounty on the question, s/he does not have to double the previous user's offer.

Comment: If your original bounty was 50. Can you extend the 7 day period by offering the another 50? Or only after that you've offered 50 then **and awarded** it then your only solution is to add a new bounty of 100?

Comment: @AstroCB so what's wrong with offering bounties indefinitely?